# how to view specific row on Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Currently my gridview shows all registered users of my game, when anyone logs in.
i would like it to just show the row of user who has just logged, specified by their username.
here is the problem, so as the user Nick is currently logged in it should just show the row where username = Nick.
How can i do this?

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Game" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:\\MAC\HOME\DESKTOP\NIMV1.MDFConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserName], [Won], [Lost], [Played] FROM [Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="UserName" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Game">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="UserName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Won" HeaderText="Won" SortExpression="Won" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Lost" HeaderText="Lost" SortExpression="Lost" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Played" HeaderText="Played" SortExpression="Played" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Comment: Why not dynamically create the `SELECT` command to only include the desired row using a `WHERE` clause? Personally, I do all my queries in code-behind and bind the results with code rather than using `SqlDataSource` objects because I find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain login-status whenever user logged in loggedout

1. Add a column as loginStatus
2. When user logged in set col **loginStatus = 1**
3. When user logout set col **loginStatus = 0**

On pageload where you bind gridview make a query like

```
Select * from tableName where loginStatus=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly hide all the unnecessary rows, checking on the fly for the one to show. I mean something like (in a kind of pseudocode, some typos possible):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow myrow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    myrow.Visible=false;
    if(myrow.Cells[0].Value == "Nick")
    {
        myrow.Visible=true;
    }
}
```